# Build MSBuild target without dependencies defined in solution

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-14.0

I'd like to invoke MSBuild to build a single project inside a solution.
Therefore I use

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /t:MyProject
```

Since I have some sophisticated deployment process and I want to save time, I need to build just the one project, but nothing else. Like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127377/5914317) I tried

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /t:MyProject /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

which works for project-to-project references, but not for project references defined by the solution (via `ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies)` in sln-file).

Does anyone know a way to ignore the solution project references also?

Comment: Build the project directly using msbuild /path/to/myproject /t:Build ?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I have some props files included (setting e.g. output directories) that use paths relative to the solution. If I build only the project (which is in a sub-folder), those paths are no longer correct...

Comment: With 'relative to solution' you mean by making use of $(SolutionDir)? You can pass those to msbuild like /p:SolutionDir=/path/to/soltuion

Comment: Good point, that should work. For my special case I have some issues with this approach (like "The filename is too long"). So I'm still interested in an answer to my question - but if there is none I will go this way. Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify? What filename is too long?

Comment: It's a Universal Windows Platform project. The (default) build process creates a folder like "output/ProjectName/AppPackages/ProjectName_versionAndConfig/ProjectName_versionAndConfig.appx". My project's name is quite long, and this seems to be too much for MakeAppx.exe.

Comment: Ok but how can there be a difference between building the solution or building a single project when both use the same paths?

Comment: Good question. I'll need to investigate...